# Import .env variable into Vuetify variables.scss

Tags: vue.js, webpack, environment-variables, vuetify.js, vue-cli

- In a Vue-cli webpack project I define an environment variable in .env file like so: `VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE=30px`
- Then in the vue.config.js I "add" it like so:

```
let sav = ''
    
if (/VUE_APP_/i.test('VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE')) {
    sav += `$${'VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE'}: "${process.env['VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE']}";`
}
    
module.exports = {
    css: {
        loaderOptions: {
            scss: {
                prependData: sav
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- Then I can use it in any .scss file like so: `font-size: unquote($VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE);`
- But if I try to use it in the Vuetify [variables.scss](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/customization/sass-variables/) file like so: `$font-size-root: $VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE;` I get the undefined variable error pointing to `$VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE`.

How do I use .env variables in Vuetify variables.scss file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are using the variables value also as variable name.
Maybe just try setting the variable name directly.

```
// vue.config.js
if (/VUE_APP_/i.test('VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE')) {
    // make sure this is executed
    sav += `$VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE: "${process.env['VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE']}";`
}

module.exports = {
  css: {
      loaderOptions: {
          scss: {
              prependData: sav
          },
          sass: {
              prependData: sav
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: I get this error: ValidationError: Invalid options object. Sass Loader has been initialized using an options object that does not match the API schema.
 - options has an unknown property 'additionalData'. These properties are valid:
   object { implementation?, sassOptions?, prependData?, sourceMap?, webpackImporter? }

Comment: It seems you use older sass loader and the key is unrelated. I edited my answer, because I am not sure why you use $${'VUE_APP_FONT_SIZE'}

Comment: Thank you very much. What was missing, it seems, was only this part:
sass: { prependData: sav }